# CMD runs EXE, launches HTML, wait until close and run final EXE

Tags: html, cmd, exe

would like have BAT file that runs set-keys.EXE, launches default.html, and then when user closes html, run set-keys-back.EXE. (they are all in the same directory together). This might be run from a CD, so I might not have ability to write a flag file and then wait to see if it is deleted in order to continue. Have already tried START /WAIT but have seen that WAIT won't actually wait for GUI 32-bit applications. Have considered one batch file calling another one, still no luck. Would prefer not to have PAUSE and user have to come back to CMD just to hit a key - seems clunky. When they close out of HTML, I execute top.window.close(). would be nice if I could put some other code after that, but I think once the window is closed it's closed - no more processing. have not been able to get WShell execute to run. HTML status bar just says error on page - no info. Would love to hear your thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:** I just figured out that you can launch IE directly without having to use the `start` command:

```
@echo off
rem You can use %SCRIPTDIR% to refer to the file to load, if you like
rem Note that %SCRIPTDIR% will contain a trailing slash!
set SCRIPTDIR=%~dp0

echo Testing this script...
C:\PROGRA~1\INTERN~1\iexplore.exe %SCRIPTDIR%foo.html
echo Continuing the script...
```

This example works for me (Windows XP 32-bit), and waits for me to close the browser window to continue.

**Update:** Here's an updated code block that launches Internet Explorer. Note that I use the short path to the `iexplore.exe` executable, and I specify the full path to the file to load:

```
@echo off
echo Testing this script...
start /wait /min cmd /C "C:\PROGRA~1\INTERN~1\iexplore.exe C:\foo.html"
echo Continuing the script...
```

**Initial Answer:** You mentioned trying the `start /wait` command, but how did you explicitly write it? The following batch script example works for me in Windows 7 x64:

```
@echo off
echo Testing this script...
start /wait /min cmd /C "%windir%\system32\notepad.exe foo.html"
echo Continuing the script...
```

In this example, the script does not continue execution until the user closes the Notepad application. The only downside here is that an extra command window pops up, but by using the `/min` parameter, we can start it minimized.

Comment: That works excellent for notepad. could I get it to launch default.html? I have tried full pathname to iexplore.exe, just iexplore.exe...when I run it it just runs all three commands sequentially, you never even see IE at all.ECHO OFF
START /B put_keys.exe
start /wait /min cmd /C "iexplore.exe +default.html"
START /B put_keys_back.exe

Comment: This works for me: `start /wait /min cmd /C "C:\PROGRA~1\INTERN~1\iexplore.exe C:\temp\test.html"`. I have to close IE for the script to continue.

Comment: super excellent so far. I agree with what you're saying. any chance to use a relative pathname or local pathname for default.html ? This will be running off a CD, and you know some people will have that as D: drive, some might be E: or who knows. It's in the same directory as the batch file and EXEs, was hoping windows would default to that directory first.

Comment: You can get the directory of the script using this snippet: `set STARTDIR=%~dp0` (all it's doing is modifying %0). See [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) for more on batch file parameter modifiers. I'll update my answer yet again with this trick.

Comment: shellexecute in the autorun.inf file invokes iexplore and stays in the resident directory to load default.html. I'm willing to try anything to wait until HTML closes before I run that last put-keys-back.exe

Comment: I've updated my answer with a method to get the directory where the script lives. You can then use that directory to get to whatever file you want (I believe you could even do a relative path this way).

Comment: You rock. A thousand appreciations. It actually worked better for me if I used SCRIPTDIR=%~dp1 and I also removed the C:\Progra~1 from the line. Just fed it %SCRIPTDIR%+default.html and it launches IE on it's own and stays in the resident directory. Alls well that ends well.